# How to get one of multiple related columns

Tags: sql

I have a notes table which stores notes about customers, jobs and products tables.
Customers, jobs and products tables have "Name" and "Id" (GUID) columns.
I want to get a note and its related object name in one query. (If my note is related to a customer, the related object name would be `customername`, and so on.)

Is it possible to do this with a single query? If so, how?

Comment: It should be possible if you share a sequence between customers / jobs / products.  It might also be possible if you share the actual schema with us.  How would you go about getting it out of a second query?

Comment: my tables look like this  http://tinypic.com/r/116nei8/6

Comment: I don't see how you can realistically know what kind of object you are pointing at.  The related obj column is effectively a union - it could be pointing at a job, customer, or product.  Any time the same id is shared by two objects it will become impossible to know what the resulting output is.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you know if it's a shared id key between the job / customer / product tables?

Comment: Actually the id columns for customer,product and job tables are Guid and there won't be a repeating entry. The actual question can be "My Notes table refers to one of these three tables and how can I find out target without knowing whether the reference of my note is a customer, a note or a job?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    notes.id,
    notes.content as content,
    coalesce(customers.name, jobs.name, products.name) as name,
    customers.id as customer_id,
    jobs.id as job_id,
    products.id as product_id
from notes
    left outer join customers on notes.relatedobjid = customers.id
    left outer join jobs      on notes.relatedobjid = jobs.id
    left outer join products  on notes.relatedobjid = products.id
;
```

Wrap this with some logic in the DAO / display code (python because it's fairly easy to read):

```
for row in query.list():
    if row["customer_id"] is not None:
        display_type = "customer name"
    elif row["job_id"] is not None:
        display_type = "job name"
    elif row["product_id"] is not None:
        display_type = "product name"
    display_note(display_type, row["name"], row["content"])
```

The extra columns and display logic may or may not be necessary, depending on how attached you are to the idea of having it say "Customer name".  I'd probably keep it, personally.  I think you could probably shuffle a lot of this logic off into your Object Relational Mapping if you have one.  That may or may not be such a hot idea, depending on how many rows you have in the notes table.

Comment: Tanks. I think this works for my situation. Actually my notes table has a column showing whether my note is about a job, product or customer. But in this situation I wanted to display just a name of related object next to my note. When its necessary I will get the details of related object separately.

Comment: Ah, yeah. You're totally looking at coalesce or similar then.  Good luck and sorry for the delay in getting back to you.